# Is there any measure satisfying given conditions

Tags: measure-theory

It may be stupid question but I would like to ask:

Let $X=\{a,b,c,d,e,f\}$. Is it possible to define a measure, such that some $A \in 2^{X}$ is not measurable with respect to that measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ denotes a [measurable space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasurableSpace.html) then a set is *measurable* it it belongs to $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal A$.

A measure $\mu$ on it that makes it a [measure space](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeasureSpace.html) $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mu)$ does not really play a part in it.

$\{X,\varnothing\}\subset\wp(X)$ is a $\sigma$-algebra and the only measurable sets are (of course) $X$ and $\varnothing$.